# Problem when deleting an answer

Tags: support, deletion

When I try to delete [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828984/5558072), I get this error message :

[image]

Why is the answer still shown, and why can't I delete my answer?

Comment: There is a limit to the amount of self-answer deletion one account can make in a day. I believe it was added to prevent mass-deletions and defacing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are limited in how many posts you can delete to prevent vandalism; there have been instances where users ragequit the site, and try to delete all their posts in the process, leading to additional moderator work to find their content and undelete it.  To curb that, the system prevents you from deleting too much of your content too quickly.